# Using grep on macOS Monterey

Tags: macos, grep, zsh

I'm trying to use grep to locate a term in files on macOS Monterey, on Linux I use:

```
grep -Rnw ./ -e "subject" --include=*.{c,cpp,js,xml}
```

This doesn't work in a terminal on macOS Monterey.  I am using Version 12.7, the terminal displays:

```
zsh: no matches found: --include=*.c
```

I've also tried:

```
grep -Rnw ./ -e "subject" -include "*.{c,cpp,js,xml}"
```

Same result, then:

```
grep -Rnw ./ -e "subject" --include "*.{c,cpp,js,xml}"
```

Nothing is displayed however I know the term is present in some of the files.

Comment: Try adding a backslash before asterix, like `--include=\*.{java,cpp}`.

Comment: On both systems, `--include=*.{c,cpp,js,xml}` attempts globbing on zsh. Whether you get the error message, depends on the settings of your zsh. For instance, if you have turned on `setopt nullglob`, the pattern is simply removed and you don't get an error message. Compare the option settings on both platforms (i.e. a plain `setopt` without argument).

Comment: A more serious problem (unrelated to your question)  is that the `grep` itself is pretty different between Linux and MacOS. For instance, a MacOS `grep -Rnw` would be written as `grep -RGnw` on Linux. If compatibility is an issue, I suggest that you install _gnu grep_ on your Mac.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the `find` command in combination with `grep` like this

```bash
find ./ -type f \( -name "*.c" -o -name "*.cpp" -o -name "*.js" -o -name "*.xml" \) -exec grep -wn "subject" {} +
```

zsh doesn't expand the brace expansion like linux

Comment: great, glad it worked for you. I was pulling my hair on a similar search 3 month back

Comment: Although as @kometen posted in the comment his solution also works.

Comment: thats cool so escaping * also works